# Url in HyperLink Field being seperated by comma of the Link Description - SharePoint List

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I have a SP List with columns URL and Link Name. And I am binding it to the GridView.

Below is my GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="false"   AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
      <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="LinkName" DataNavigateUrlFields="URL" Target="_blank"/>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and on the code behind

```
  private void BindGridView(SPList list, string section, GridView grdView1)
    {
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=" + section + "/><Value Type='Choice'>" + section + "</Value></Eq</Where>";
        query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='URL'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='LinkName'/>";
        SPListItemCollection listCollection = list.GetItems(query);
        if (listCollection != null && listCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            grdView1.DataSource = listCollection.GetDataTable();
            grdView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Suppose I have the Link Name as Google and URL as www.google.com.

When I click on the hyperlink field of the GridView, the URL in the brower is **//goog.com,%20//goo.com**, because of which it does not navigate to the URL.

Someone please help me and let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way to use the Url Value field is by using the `SPFieldUrlValue` object.

Ex:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>();
foreach (SPListItem item in listCollection)
{
    urls.Add(new SPFieldUrlValue(item["URL"]).Url);
}
grdView1.DataSource = urls;
```